# How to deal with WCF connection failing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Let's imagine I have WCF service and a client that consumes some methods from a given service.
There are tons of posts of how to handle various exceptions during the client and service communication. Only thing which is still confusing me is a following case:

Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool ExportData(object data);
}
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public bool ExportData(object data)
    {
        // Simulate long operation (i.e. inserting data to the DB)
        Thread.Sleep(1000000);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    static wsService1.Service1Client client1 = new wsService1.Service1Client();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object data = GetRecordsFromLocalDB();

        bool result = client1.ExportData(data);

        if (result)
        {
            DeleteRecordsFromLocalDB();
        }
    }
}
```

Client gets some data from local db and sending it to the server. If result is successful, then client is going to remove exported rows from local DB. Now imagine, when data is already sent to the server, suddenly connection failed (i.e. WiFi was disconnected). In this case data is successfully processed on a server side, but client is never know about it. And yes, I can catch connection exception, but still I don't know what should I do with a records in my local DB. I can send this data again later, but I'll get some duplication on a server DB (i.e. duplication is allowed on remote DB), but I don't want to send same data multiple times.

So, my question is how to handle such cases? What is the best practices?
I checked some info about [asynchronous operations.](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-in-wcf.html) But still this is about when I have stable connection. 
As a workaround I can store my export operation under some GUID remotelly and check status for this GUID later. Only thing I can't change remote DB. So, please, suggest what would be better in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points to consider

1. On server side you can catch all kinds of error (custom class deriving IErrorHandler) and provide specific error to client letting him know about error's reason.
2. The concept of service is that it is kind of intermediary between client and database so why would client retrieve data and then send it to service?
3. One way out is to use transaction which assures that if error occurres then no changes are going to be retained.

By the way, If you expect service to throw an exception do not create global service object since it will end up being in faulted state. Create new instance for every single call instead (make use of using statement so as to dispose its instance). Bool return type does not provide extensive information about the error if any takes place. Let it have void return type and wrap in try/catch block which gives a change to learn more about the source and nature of error.

Comment: Generally WCF services return exception details in a `FaultException` rather than exposing a global `IErrorHandler` object to clients (which if the server is down they won't be able to reach anyway). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee942778.aspx